# How to append info data next the bar in chartist.js used in angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, chartist.js, angular-chartist.js

I want to add info data next to the selected line bar in the chartist.js library that is used inside an angular component in the highlighted yellow portion in the attached picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QothB.png)